# vertically center absolutely-positioned image while using object-fit

Tags: css

How do I vertically center an image while using `object-fit: cover`? I would like the image to always be 100% of the width of its container, and the top and bottom of the image to be cropped when the height of the container is smaller than the height of the image. `object-fit: cover` only crops the bottom of the image by default. In the example below, I want the center of the image to always be directly behind the text.

```css
header {
  max-height: 20em;
  position:   relative;
}

h1 {
  position:   absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top:        0;
  transform:  translateY(-50%);
  width:      100%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity:    0.2;
  z-index:    -1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <img src=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Widdringtonia_whytei_Mulanje_Malawi.jpg>
</header>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you want the layout to be. Is the text (in this case just the h1) to be positioned vertically centrally in the header element? Why the translate(-50%) on it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `object-position` in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).